# How to write a custom action in Views VBO to print a batch of selected invoices

Tags: views, commerce

I need a custom action in Views VBO with Drupal Commerce to print a selected group of invoices to a browser print dialog. I have configured this as a src plugin and a custom twig template.  Here is an example of the code in the action .php:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_action_module\Plugin\Action;

use Drupal\Core\Action\ActionBase;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface;

/**
 * Prints an invoice for the selected order(s).
 *
 * @Action(
 *   id = "print_invoice_action",
 *   label = @Translation("Print Invoice"),
 *   type = "commerce_order"
 * )
 */
class PrintInvoiceAction extends ActionBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function execute($entities = []) {
    if (!empty($entities)) {
      foreach ($entities as $entity) {
        if ($entity instanceof OrderInterface) {
          $this->printInvoice($entity);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Print the invoice for an order.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface $order
   *   The order entity.
   */
protected function printInvoice(OrderInterface $order) {
  // Get the array of orders from the context.
  $orders = $this->getContextValue('entity');

  // Initialize the output variable.
  $output = '';

  // Loop through each order and generate the invoice output.
  foreach ($orders as $order) {
    // Render the Twig template with the order entity.
    $build = [
      '#theme' => 'mymodule_theme_template',
      '#order' => $order,
    ];

    // Render the Twig template.
    $output .= \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($build);
  }

  // Set the content type to HTML.
  $headers = ['Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=utf-8'];

  // Print the invoice output with JavaScript to trigger the print dialog.
  print '<html><head><title>Invoice</title></head>';
  print '<body onload="print();">';
  print '<div id="invoice-container">' . $output . '</div>';
  print '</body></html>';
  exit;
}
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function access($object, AccountInterface $account = NULL, $return_as_object = FALSE) {
    return $object instanceof OrderInterface;
  }

}
```

So far I cannot get the print dialog of the browser to open my selected group of invoices

Comment: There are print and exit statements in the code sample—most unusual for Drupal code.